# Stop users from doing the same Google Docs survey twice

Tags: google-drive

I'm using Google Docs to host a simple survey and I noticed that the same person can keep filling out the survey over and over again.

How do I stop users from doing the survey more than once?

Is it possible to block multiple survey responses per user?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays there is a inbuilt feature:
Simply enable the "Only allow one response per person" in the "Form Settings".

The downside is that each user needs to login with their Google account (which they might not have, or they might not want to use).

Source: http://www.labnol.org/internet/prevent-multiple-form-submissions/28675/

Answer (score 1):

No inbuilt feature as such but there is of course a workaround by which you create a special token question and provide each customer with a unique token they have to enter into the form. You can then filter the results on valid tokens only and e.g. use only the first or last form submit with a valid token.

The drawback is that you will have to create a way (Google Apps Script comes to mind) to send each customer an e-mail with the unique token and the link to the form.

You can refer here for info on Google Apps Script:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=182a8d20077a57e1&hl=en